# Is it possible to use Flatgeobuf in Python?

Tags: python, gis, flatbuffers

I would like to read from / write to [flatgeobuffers](https://github.com/flatgeobuf/flatgeobuf) from a Python GIS application. My understanding is that this technology can only be used so in JavaScript and TypeScript (of course the compilation stage is language-agnostic insofar as the official CLI does that just fine).

It there a known technique or workaround to read from / write to flatgeobuffers in Python?

Comment: I wrote a simple Python module binding to Rust for this purpose but I would be happy to learn that there's a way to use flatgeobuf natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [Fiona](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html#python-usage) and subsequently [Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-and-writing-files) can read and write FlatGeobuf. [GDAL](https://gdal.org/) is the backend driver doing the work.